# How to get the months of the year in order

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I have this code which is used to get the days of the week starting of the current.

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    System.out.println(df.format(calendar.getTime()));
}
```

I want edit the code to get the months of the year in the same way - starting from the present month. Can you help me to edit the code.

Comment: Peter, you should take some time to think by yourself, and read the javadoc. You won't learn much by asking for every little problem you have. You already have the algorithm, and reading the javadoc would immediately give you the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Calendar.MONTH`. With minimal changes to your code, it'll look like this:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    System.out.println(df.format(calendar.getTime()));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, you *could* set the day of the month to 1 (just for sanity) and then just add a month on each step instead of a day. Alternatively, you could just use:

```
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(locale);
String[] months = symbols.getMonths();
```

... and go from there.

You could use `getWeekdays` in the same way for the day names, too.

Answer (score 1):

In JodaTime you can do new DateTime() and then do plusMonths(1) to add one month. This will return the date one month on. You can then parse that to get the month.  Then repeat 11 times to get the rest of the months.

This link will help to get the month name http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_instant.html